# N issues detected - Umbraco Major version upgrade from 6.2.0 to 7.1.8

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco6, umbraco-blog, umbraco-contour

Currently upgrading from 6.2.0 to 7.1.8. and I am stuck.

During the upgrade installer I have been shown a dialog window saying

Major version upgrade from 6.2.0 to 7.1.8

There were 1 issue detected

Property Editor with ID 'c2d6894b-e788-4425-bcf2-308568e3d38b' (assigned to Data Type 'Multinode Picker') does not have a valid GUID -> Alias map. It will be replaced with a Readonly/Label property editor.
The following compatibility issues were found. If you continue all non-compatible property editors will be converted to a Readonly/Label. You will be able to change the property editor to a compatible type manually by editing the data type after installation.

The installer is giving me the option to continue or fix it before I continue,

can some one explain why I am getting this message and how to fix it?

Thanks Ayo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Multinode Picker' is incompatible with the new version of Umbraco.
You are getting this warning because one or more property editors is using this data-type.

Umbraco's default behavior when you select 'Continue' is to simply replace the the data type with a noedit label.

After the conversion, you can go to Developer > Data types, and find the multinode picker. In the dropdown it will probably be set as 'noedit' now. I believe you should set it to Multi-Node Treepicker manually.

If I recall correctly, the Multi-node Treepicker stores the selected nodes in the same CSV format as the old version, so you shouldn't lose any data... I think :)

Comment: That is actually the right answer! I clicked continue and yes your right..  but please have a look at this umbraco fourm thread > http://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/59231-N-issues-detected-Major-version-upgrade-from-620-to-718-?p=0#comment200133  Having a slightly different problem now